# Setup flask application for test, stage, prod environments

Tags: python, flask, dockerfile

So I have a requirement in which I have a flask app with multiple python files. Each file has some variables like API_URL, DEVICE_CONTEXT etc. which will be common in all python files. These variables will be decided by the type of environment i.e. test or stage or prod. So based on the environment mode, I need to populate the variables in each of the python files for my flask app. Please can someone tell me what is the standard way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More or less native way for Flask to configure enviroment is to use app.config variable in the following way:

```py
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_envvar('SOME_SYSTEM_ENVIROMENT_VARIABLE')
    api_url = app.config['API_URL'] #access to any parameter
```

Where SOME_SYSTEM_ENVIROMENT_VARIABLE point to the file with a config that represents your environment (testing, prod et.c.). This file is written in the fashion:

```
API_URL = 'http://localhost:9999'
```

For each of your environment you have to define separate config file and setup enviroment variable before running Flask.
There are also several other ways to config the enviroment, you can read [this](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/config/) about them.